# Angular Selective Import / Injection

Tags: angular

Is it possible in Angular 8 to selective import / inject at runtime? I have an old service that I want to use in a new project in the same ng-cli workspace, but the new project uses the built in Angular routing, while the old one uses a 3rd party routing.

So in the constructor of the service I can do this

```
    let app = this.config.get('application');
    if (app == 'legacy') {
        this.state = this.injector.get<any>(StateService);
    }
```

Which means I don't need to inject it, but the new project code still fails because the StateService does not have provider

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError:
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[StateService]:   
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[StateService]: 
     NullInjectorError: No provider for StateService! Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for StateService!
```

Which I know because I don't want to use it. Is there a way to do this without importing the 3rd party module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code in OP was working just fine.

```
let app = this.config.get('application');
if (app == 'legacy') {
    this.state = this.injector.get<any>(StateService);
}
```

is all that is needed, the issue in my case was the if statement. (The config service was loading data from the wrong place so the if was always true)

I would add the caveat that I an using the cli generated services from angular 6+ that are provided for the root

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
```

In case that makes any difference to people with a similar issue in the future.

Comment: Ah the taste of humble from a silly public mistake lol hope it helps someone else at least :)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a another provider https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers

```
// old project
providers: [
{ provide: StateService, useValue: OldStateService }
],

// new project
providers: [
{ provide: StateService, useValue: NewStateService }
],
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always create providers in run time:

```
Injector.create({providers: [...]})
```